# Add new column to users table via migration wont take effect

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, migration

Iam trying to add a column to existing collection. Iam using MongoDB
Iam running the following migraion:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddLocaleColumn extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->string('locale')->default(config('app.locale'));
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::table('users', function ($table) {
        $table->dropColumn('locale');
    });
}
```

}

When i execute 'php artisan migrate' the respond i get is good:

```
php artisan migrate
Migrating: 2020_01_01_000000_add_locale_column
Migrated:  2020_01_01_000000_add_locale_column
```

When i then go to the 'robomongo 3t studio' to verify that the new column has been created, i cant see it

Have i missed something. Iam new to mongodb and laravel so bare with me.

Comment: Everything looks ok at a glance... Is `DESCRIBE users` a valid MongoDB command? That (or the equivalent, don't know Mongo syntax sorry) should list the columns for the `users` table.

Comment: iam also using this mongodb command to check if the new column exist: db.users.find({ 'locale' : { '$exists' : true }}).pretty(); but this also returns negative result

Comment: Hmm... Well, everything looks ok to me. Are you sure you're checking the right database? What happens if you run `php artisan migrate` again? (It should say "Nothing to migrate")

Comment: Yes that is exactly what i get when i try it again

Comment: The means the migration was successful. Do you see the migration in `SELECT * FROM migrations`? There should be a row (the most recent) for `2020_01_01_000000_add_locale_column`

Comment: Yup i can see the row... so wierd. Iam new to mongodb so iam affraid that i have missed something very simple

Comment: And what do you get with `SELECT locale FROM users`? You should get a bunch of rows with the same value as `config('app.locale')`

Comment: i get nothing unfortunately

Comment: But no error? If the column didn't exist, you'd get something like `Unknown column \`users.locale\``

Comment: No error. Iam using robo 3t studio. which is equivalent to sql manager studio but for mongodb. So i dont get error. I tried SELECT blablabla FROM users just to try. I get the same respond when i select my new column

Comment: Maybe migrating dont work with mongodb

Comment: That's super bizarre... It _should_ work with MongoDB, as Laravel is designed to be "database-agnostic" (meaning all DB languages, including MongoDB, should work with minimal configuration). I'm afraid I'm at a loss :(

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not have columns (or any schema) in collections. **Individual documents** may have various fields, and the set of fields can vary from one document to the next.

The operation of "adding a column to a collection" does not make sense in MongoDB. You can only add  **values** for a particular field to individual documents.

By the same token, you generally do not need to have or run migrations to adjust the schema when using MongoDB, you can simply insert any fields you like at any time.

(*Data migration* is different and is a valid use case for migrations in MongoDB context.)

Comment: So how would i go about if i wanted to update a existing collection with a new field and at the same time populate the field with data for every document of that collection

Comment: You could use a migration for that.

Comment: do you know how?

Comment: That is a separate question.